# How can I remove css rules apply on dashboard in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, dashboard

How can I remove css rules apply on dashboard in wordpress?
I make a theme and the css rules are applied inside the dashboard.

In functions.php is write this code :

```
wp_register_style('styles',get_bloginfo('template_url')."/css/styles.css");
wp_register_style('bootstrap',get_bloginfo('template_url')."/css/bootstrap.css");
wp_register_style('bootstrap-responsive',get_bloginfo('template_url')."/css/bootstrap-responsive.css");
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-responsive');
wp_enqueue_style('styles');
```

Comment: Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_bloginfo('template_url')`, so your theme will be child-theme ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's spilling in the admin area because you need to wrap all that in the appropriate hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

function my_enqueue()
{
    // Register and enqueue CSS and JS here
}
```

See: [Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: Yes, I did this function and i put this on header.php and it works. Thanks.

Comment: No, not in header. In functions.php.